# xpatch поиск по одному из значений атребута

Tags: css, xpath

Есть `div`

```
<div class="dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success dz-complete"></div>
```

Я могу его найти так:

```
//*[@class='dz-preview dz-processing dz-image-preview dz-success dz-complete']
```

А можно ли его найти по одному из значению `dz-complete` атрибута `class` ?

Comment: `//*[contains(@class, 'dz-complete')]` или `//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' dz-complete ')]`

Comment: @Deonis Второй вариант просто гениален. Оформите его в виде ответа

Comment: Кто-нибудь другой. Нет времени